# Can I update the documents in a single updateMany query or I have to hit the update query multiple times?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a "Delivery" schema with a field called "deliverySubZoneSets" which is an array of objects,

```
"deliverySubZoneSets" : [ 
        {
            "charges" : {
                "delivery" : 30,
                "service" : 0,
                "packing" : 0,
                "parking" : 50
            },
            "areas" : [ 
                ObjectId("5d99c2a93a6a615ff9f7355a")
            ],
            "deliveryAvgMaxTime" : 30,
        }
    ]
```

I want to update all the existing records of "Delivery" having "deliverySubZoneSets", with "deliveryAvgMaxTimeInUnits" where I will be storing value with units

```
"deliveryAvgMaxTimeInUnits": {
    "value":30,
    "units":"minutes"
}
```

So that my array looks like this-

```
"deliverySubZoneSets" : [ 
            {
                "charges" : {
                    "delivery" : 30,
                    "service" : 0,
                    "packing" : 0,
                    "parking" : 50
                },
                "areas" : [ 
                    ObjectId("5d99c2a93a6a615ff9f7355a")
                ],
                "deliveryAvgMaxTime" : 30,
                "deliveryAvgMaxTimeInUnits": {
                   "value":30,
                   "units":"minutes"
                }
            }
        ]
```

I can do it by iterating through the array and then perform multiple update operations but can I do this in a single updateMany query?

Comment: What is the condition query you want to update with? are you using array of `_id`s ?

Comment: @Thee Sritabtim deliverySubZoneSets.length > 0

Comment: The value in deliveryAvgMaxTimeInUnits will be always 30?

Comment: @PuneetSingh No. It is dynamic. Based on deliveryAvgMaxTime.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do it in a single query

Comment: So, basically you want to set `deliveryAvgMaxTimeInUnits` according to  `deliveryAvgMaxTime` and `units` will allways be in minutes?

Comment: Yes thats right

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB 4.2 or later, you can perform [updates with pipelines](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

Which enables you to update documents based on current values in the document.

For your case you'll have to use `$map` and `$mergeObject`

```js
db.collection.updateMany({
  deliverySubZoneSets: { $ne: [] }
}, [
  {
    $set: {
      deliverySubZoneSets: {
        $map: {
          input: "$deliverySubZoneSets",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                deliveryAvgMaxTimeInUnits: {
                  value: "$$this.deliveryAvgMaxTime",
                  units: "minutes"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Running this in Robo 3T shell, getting error
Failed to execute script.

Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators 
Details:
DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:625:1
@(shell):1:1

Comment: Looks like my db version is 3.4.23. Any solution ?

Comment: @Shambhavi_RB version 3.4 has already reached [end of life date](https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy) it's advised to update your version. Otherwise you will have to call the update queries multiple times